# How do I Deserialize the following JSON string with the .NET JavaScriptSerializer class?

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

I have the following JSON object:

```
[{"newValue":"{\"id\":\"1\",\"desc\":\"description\"}",
"oldValue":"{\"id\":\"2\",\"desc\":\"description2\"}"}]
```

`newValue` is holds the new values for the object I want to deserialize into and `oldValue` contains the old values for the object I want to deserialize into, but I am not sure how to deserialize each one individually or can it be done together?

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged javascript instead of C#? Unless it's happening server side in C# code please change the tag to javascript.

Comment: I'll endorse @evanmcdonnal's question: is this on C# or Javascript?

Comment: @AndreCalil - I am using JavaScriptSerializer from .NET, so that is why I used both tags.

Comment: @I4V - The original string was had around 100 strings each so I just shortened it. In doing so I may have took out some  `"`

Comment: No constructive responses.

Comment: @Xaisoft: So you you want to deserialize in JavaScript or with .NET? What tool has built the JSON is irrelevant.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll ask again, differently: are you trying to make that deserialization using C# ou Javascript?

Comment: @AndreCalil - Look at the title of the question, it says JavaScriptSerializer which is part of the .NET, so C#.  I modified it so you can understand it better.

Comment: @Xaisoft that's so kind of you. It's hard to understand why you hadn't write a clear question neither used the according tags.

Comment: @AndreCalil - Don't mention it.  Why was the tag changed to javascript when I am using c# for deserializing?

Answer (score 1):

Your json is a little bit weird, since the value of *newValue* and *oldValue* is **string**, not object. It seems that they are double-serialized.  Below code works (by first deserializing the whole json string, and then the *old/new/values*)

```
var jArr = JArray.Parse(json);
var anon = new { id = 0, desc = "" };
var items = jArr.Select(item => new
             {
                 NewValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(item["newValue"].ToString(),anon),
                 OldValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(item["oldValue"].ToString(),anon)
             })
             .ToList();
```

Comment: I am calling JSON.stringify on them, would it be better if I did not do that?

Comment: JArray represents a [JSON array](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jarray.htm)

Comment: @QtX - Is it possible to do it without Json.Net?

Comment: @QtX - If my object contains literally 100 rows, would I have to explicitly declare each of them in the anon variable?

Comment: @Xaisoft 1) Without Json.Net? I think you should find it by yourself (Maybe someone can post an answer using other serializers). I generally use Json.Net 2) No,  one `anon` is enough as long as the properties(names and their types) are equal